# Understanding return data type C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I'm playing on CodeWars and i can't solve the task because of the function return data type. Please help me understand what does

> long long (*convertFrac)[2]

mean? And why my return data type is not suitable? Could somebody explain me, or give a hint how to properly google such question? I thought that allocating memory and returning a pointer would be fine, but it is not.

```
long long (*convertFrac(long long lst[][2], int row))[2] {
  long long **out = malloc(row*sizeof(long long*));
  long long * result = (long long *)malloc(row*2*sizeof(long long));
  for (size_t i = 0; i < row; i++)
  {
    out[i] = result+i*2;
  }
  ...
  return out;
}
```

example:

```
long long (*data)[2] = convertFrac((long long [][2]){ {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4} }, 3); // data should be {{6, 12}, {4, 12}, {3, 12}}
```

Comment: Read this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean-in-c-cplusplus

Comment: @RobertHarvey yep it is an array of pointers

Comment: Well, pointers are pointers, not long longs.  I assume you want to return a long long?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm given a function prototype, that a can not change, and i can't undestand what hides behind  long long (*convertFrac())[2].

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your function signature.  It looks like it's taking a function pointer as a parameter, but then the third array element is being retrieved.  Does that even compile?

Comment: OK, what is the function's purpose? What is it supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it has to reduce to a common denominator an array of rationals. I updated information with an example.

Comment: your out and result do not make any sense and it is one large UB

Comment: Where is `n` defined in the function?  Should it be `row`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Arrays are not the same as pointers.** The type `long long (*)[2]` is a pointer to an array of 2 `long long`s. The type `long long **` is a pointer to a pointer to a `long long`. The two types are not compatible.

To declare something of type `long long (*)[2]` the *something* goes between the `*` and the `)`. For example, a simple variable `foo` of type `long long (*)[2]` would be declared as `long long (*foo)[2];`. For a function returning `long long (*)[2]`, it is the function name and its list of parameters that goes between the `*` and `)`. For example, a function `bar` taking a single parameter `int a` and returning a `long long (*)[2]` would be declared as `long long (*bar(int a))[2];`.

From the question, it appears that the function `convertFrac` is supposed to copy an array of fractions (with each fraction represented by a `long long [2]`) and convert them to use a common denominator. The following code does most of that, apart from calculating the common denominator:

```
long long lcm(long long a, long long b); // to be written

long long (*convertFrac(long long lst[][2], int row))[2] {
  long long (*result)[2] = malloc(row*sizeof(*result));
  long long d;
  int i;

  // determine common denominator
  d = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    d = lcm(d, lst[i][1];
  }

  // convert fractions to common denominator
  for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    result[i][0] = lst[i][0] * (d / lst[i][1]);
    result[i][1] = d;
  }

  return result;
}
```

A suitable `typedef` for the fraction type would make the code more readable:

```
typedef long long fraction[2];

fraction *convertFrac(fraction lst[], int row) {
  fraction *result = malloc(row*sizeof(*result));
  ...
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Note that the code above assumes each input fraction is already in its simplest form. If that is not the case, a bit more work is needed, but that is a bit out of scope for the question.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution worked for me. But still I have to find out the difference between int *ptr; and int arr[]; If you know a book, please provide me with it's name.

Comment: @fakamakato [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is a good list of books. The arrays and pointers confusion for beginners is because in many expressions, an array object gets replaced with a pointer to its first element (the array "decays" to a pointer). After `int a[3]; int *b;`, in the statement `b = a;`, the array `a` decays to a pointer to its first element (equivalent to `&a[0]`) and the pointer is assigned to `b`. The `[` `]` operator actually _only_ works on pointer values and relies on array values decaying to pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`long long (*convertFrac)[2]` is a pointer.  A pointer to an array 2 of `long long`.

A useful site is [C gibberish ↔ English](https://cdecl.org/?q=long+long+%28*convertFrac%29%5B2%5D)

---

Returning `long long **out` is not compatible with returning a `long long (*)[2]`.  Simply return a `long long (*)[2]`.

Looks like OP wants to allocate and assign with a computation based on the given *compound literal*. To do so

```
#define COL_N 2

long long (*convertFrac(long long lst[][COL_N], int row))[COL_N] {
  // Corrected and simplified allocation
  long long (*data)[COL_N] = malloc(sizeof *data * (size_t) row);
  if (data == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  // At this point, there is some calculation of the LCD based on lst.
  // I'll leave that calculation to OP as the question is about return types.
  long long lcm = lcm(lst, row);

  for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
    long long multiplier = lcm/lst[r][COL_N-1];
    for (int c = 0; c < COL_N; c++) {
      data[r][c] = multiplier*lst[r][c];
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes is good to typedef to make it more human readable

```
typedef long long lla2[2];

lla2 *foo()
{
    long long (*data)[2] = malloc(sizeof(*data));

    return data;
}

lla2 *bar()
{
    lla2 *data = malloc(sizeof(*data));

    return data;
}

lla2 *noo(lla2 *ptr)
{
    return ptr + 1;
}
```

And your function signature will be

```
lla2 *convertFrac(lla2 *lst, int row)
```

The body of the function does not make any sense so it dificult to say what you want to archieve

Comment: If you're going to do this, at least give it a meaningful name.

Comment: @RobertHarvey long long array of two elements - lla2